# Delay when getting rtsp stream from Kurento

Tags: webrtc, rtsp, kurento

I am running kurento-media-server with this: https://github.com/lulop-k/kurento-rtsp2webrtc
example. OK, I am getting rtsp stream but it appears with delay about 3-4 seconds. As I saw in this post: [How to disable video encoding In Kurento Media Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564536/how-to-disable-video-encoding-in-kurento-media-server)
that can be because encoding running on the Kurento media sever. The problem is that I cannot install the openh264-gst-plugins-bad-1.5 because I am running 32 bit Ubuntu so I have to build it by myself. Currently I succeeded to build all packages but not this one! So as I saw in the google group it may be another way to distribute the rtsp media. Can you explain how to distribute media with WebRTC instead of HTTP streaming?

Comment: OK, the openh264-gst-plugins-bad-1.5 is installed. Still getting delay (

Answer (score 0):

Following this https://github.com/Kurento/kms-elements/pull/3 article I recompiled the kms-elements and now I have no delay at all!!!